# Detecting when an aux cable is connected to phone

Tags: python, cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am wondering if there's a way of detecting when an aux cable is connected to a phone using Ionic2?

I am assuming, since there is a way it detects when the earphones are plugged in there should be a way of detecting when just an aux cable is connected but I wasn't able to find any documentation on how to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, you have an Ionic2 application, and on a smartphone, you want to be able to do something when the USB cable is pluged ? 

I don't know Ionic, but you can do it with NodeJS : https://github.com/tessel/node-usb

And there is some cordova plugin to handle battery and USB, so you should use it maybe

Comment: Correct, I have an Ionic2 application which I'd like to use to detect if an aux cable is plugged in. Do you think the functionality provided by the examples you've given would also work for aux cables, since what the documentation doesn't seem to specify it?

Comment: i don't know but there is a UsbDetection section which Attaches a callback to plugging in a device. It guess it notify you when a USB cable is plugged